# Blazor load elements on layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

How to load only the navbar section A when page A is open or how to know what page is load in the layout?

**Layout:**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<NavMenu />
<div class="container">
    @Body
</div>
```

**NavMenu**

```
<nav class="navbar">
<div>elementA</div>
<div>elementB</div>
</nav>
```

**Page A:**

```
@Page "/PageA"
<div class="row">
...
</div>
```

**Page B:**

```
@Page "/PageB"
<div class="row">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NavigationManager.Uri` can get current uri.You can check if it contains `PageA` or `PageB` in the Uri.You can change the NavMenu as the following shows:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
<nav class="navbar">
                @{ if (NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("PageA"))
                    {
                        <div>elementA</div>
                    }
                    else if (NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("PageB"))
                    {
                        <div>Fetch Data</div>
                    } 
                 }
            </nav>
```

Here is a demo:

NavMenu:

```
<nav class="navbar" style="color:white">
    @{ if (NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("counter"))
        {
            <div>counter</div>
        }
        else if (NavigationManager.Uri.Contains("fetch"))
        {
            <div>fetch data</div>
        } }
</nav>
```

Counter:

```
@page "/counter"
...
```

FetchData:

```
@page "/fetchdata"
...
```

result:
[image]